# nodered on Raspberry PI is not starting any longer

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I am not quite sure what node is causing this behaviour and there are tooo many flows so I can not install from scratch and yes I do not have a backup of them.
I realized today in the morning that I can not access the http gui of my nodered instance any longer on my raspberrypi zero. Just edited some flows but nothing real serious.

I am trying to start my node red on my Rapsberry PI zere and no GUI and UI is starting up to access the node red instance. I don't know how to solve and troubleshoot this. What I am doing or trying to do is:

```
pi@nodered-pi:~/.node-red $ node-red-start

Start Node-RED

Once Node-RED has started, point a browser at http://192.168.1.42:1880
On Pi Node-RED works better with the Firefox or Chrome browser

Use   node-red-stop                          to stop Node-RED
Use   node-red-start                         to start Node-RED again
Use   node-red-log                           to view the recent log output
Use   sudo systemctl enable nodered.service  to autostart Node-RED at every boot
Use   sudo systemctl disable nodered.service to disable autostart on boot

To find more nodes and example flows - go to http://flows.nodered.org

Starting as a systemd service.
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
19 Aug 15:13:55 - [info]
Welcome to Node-RED
===================
19 Aug 15:13:55 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.7
19 Aug 15:13:55 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.11.1
19 Aug 15:13:55 - [info] Linux 4.14.52+ arm LE
19 Aug 15:14:06 - [info] Loading palette nodes
19 Aug 15:14:37 - [info] Dashboard version 2.9.6 started at /ui
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [warn] [node-red-contrib-delta-timed/delta-time] 'delta' already registered by module node-red-contrib-change-detect
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [info] Settings file  : /home/pi/.node-red/settings.js
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [info] User directory : /home/pi/.node-red
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [warn] Projects disabled : set editorTheme.projects.enabled=true to enable
19 Aug 15:14:49 - [info] Flows file     : /home/pi/.node-red/flows_nodered-pi.json
19 Aug 15:14:50 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
19 Aug 15:14:50 - [warn]
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.
If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.
You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
19 Aug 15:14:50 - [warn] Error loading credentials: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
19 Aug 15:14:50 - [warn] Error loading flows: Error: Failed to decrypt credentials
19 Aug 15:14:51 - [info] Starting flows
19 Aug 15:15:01 - [warn] [telegram receiver:Telegram Receiver] bot not initialized
19 Aug 15:15:01 - [warn] [telegram sender:Temperatur Wetterstation] bot not initialized.
19 Aug 15:15:01 - [error] [function:Versorge mit Information] SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
19 Aug 15:15:01 - [info] Started flows
19 Aug 15:15:02 - [info] [sonoff-server:166ef3ba.0029bc] SONOFF Server Started On Port 1080
19 Aug 15:15:02 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
19 Aug 15:15:02 - Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nodered.service: Unit entered failed state.
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nodered.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
19 Aug 15:15:20 - [info]
Welcome to Node-RED
===================
19 Aug 15:15:20 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.7
```

Comment: What did you change? Is this a migration from another machine? have you upgraded NodeJS?

Comment: npm uninstall node-red-contrib-sonoff-server

Comment: npm uninstall node-red-contrib-telegrambot

Comment: EDIT the question to add detail

Comment: Node.js  version: v8.11.3

Comment: Also please read the doc on how to ask a good Stack Overflow question, your last 2 really do not make it easy to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
19 Aug 15:15:02 - Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
```

This error implies that something else is already running on port 443. This could be an existing copy of Node-RED or something else. You can search what applications are listening on what ports with the following command

```
lsof -i :443
```

This will list what is listening on port 443